# ¿Como abrir un PDF, sin guardarlo?, usando iTextSharp, y C#

Tags: c#, itextsharp

Estoy trabajando con iTextSharp. Utilizó una función para generar un archivo PDF, y guardarlo, con el siguiente fragmento de código:

```
//GENERAR ARCHIVO PDF.
    private void To_pdf()
    {
        Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate(), 10, 10, 10, 10);
        SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
        saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"C:";
        saveFileDialog1.Title = "Guardar Reporte";
        saveFileDialog1.DefaultExt = "pdf";
        saveFileDialog1.Filter = "pdf Files (*.pdf)|*.pdf| All Files (*.*)|*.*";
        saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
        saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
        string filename = "";
        if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            filename = saveFileDialog1.FileName;
        }

        if (filename.Trim() != "")
        {
            FileStream file = new FileStream(filename,
            FileMode.OpenOrCreate,
            FileAccess.ReadWrite,
            FileShare.ReadWrite);
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, file);
            doc.Open();
            string remito = "ARCHIVO PDF DE PRUEBA";
            string envio = "Fecha:" + DateTime.Now.ToString();

            //AGERGAR UNA IMÁGEN.
            iTextSharp.text.Image imagen = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance("C:/Users/ABG/Desktop/SistemaNóminaABG/Imágenes/grupoabg.png");
            Chunk chunk = new Chunk("Reporte de General bitacora", FontFactory.GetFont("ARIAL", 20, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD));
            doc.Add(new Paragraph(chunk));
            doc.Add(new Paragraph("------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"));
            doc.Add(imagen);
            doc.Add(new Paragraph(remito));
            doc.Add(new Paragraph(envio));
            //GenerarDocumento(doc);
            doc.AddCreationDate();
            doc.Add(new Paragraph("______________________________________________", FontFactory.GetFont("ARIAL", 20, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD)));
            doc.Add(new Paragraph("Firma", FontFactory.GetFont("ARIAL", 20, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD)));
            doc.Close();
            Process.Start(filename);//Esta parte se puede omitir, si solo se desea guardar el archivo, y que este no se ejecute al instante
        }

    }
```

Y, después lo que hago es mostrarlo en un FORM de mi programa, llamando a la ruta del archivo.

Lo que yo quiero saber es..., ¿Como le hago para mostrar el archivo PDF en el form, sin tener que guardarlo?, es decir, que al crearlo directamente se abra.

Les agradezco.

Comment: Me parece que no se puede generar el PDF sin guardarlo. De todas formas en qué te complica que lo guarde si por ejemplo cada vez que lo generas con el mismo nombre sobreescribe al anterior?

Comment: Agradezco tu respuesta. :) Mira, la razón de por qué no quiero que se almacenen automáticamente es que debo generar cientos de archivos de Nómina, y primero hay que visualizarlos antes de generarlos.

Comment: Entiendo, entonces prueba usar System.IO.MemoryStream en lugar de FileStream. 

En este enlace tienes un ejemplo:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7761007/open-generated-pdf-file-through-code-directly-without-saving-it-onto-the-disk

Comment: Otro ejemplo:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40669394/display-pdf-without-saving

Comment: Ejemplo excelentemente explicado y en video te comparto el link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m1kP_7JcfyA&list=PLoKHRphwEEtQn9ZXedAZeZkI2o4FV6DQh&index=19&t=322s Espero te sirva Saludos

Answer (score 3):

[`FileStream`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream?view=netframework-4.7.2) herada de [`System.IO.Stream`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream?view=netframework-4.7.2), por lo que en vez de enviar un `FileStream` al metodo `PdfWriter.GetInstance();`, intenta enviando un `MemoryStream` ya que FileStream requiere crear el archivo en disco:

```
// ...
var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms);
doc.Open();
//...
```

Entonces cuando termines de generar y cerrar el documento, obtienes los bytes del pdf utilizando el metodo `MemoryStream#ToArray()`:

```
byte[] pdfBytes = ms.ToArray();
```

Codigo:

```
private void To_pdf()
{
    //...

    if (filename.Trim() != "")
    {
        MemoryStream file = new MemoryStream();
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, file);
        doc.Open();
        string remito = "ARCHIVO PDF DE PRUEBA";
        string envio = "Fecha:" + DateTime.Now.ToString();

        //..
        doc.Close();

        // obtienes los datos del pdf generado
        var pdfBytes = file.ToArray();


    }

}
```